# JQuery For Loop "ignores" it's content

Tags: jquery, for-loop

I am trying to create a jquery 'for loop' that is used to get image urls from an array and use them to change a background of a div with class ".mobile".

The array is filled up with 3 urls. The problem is that the first and second urls are ignored and the third image is displayed 3 times. Also, I tried inserting an alert to see what the "i" variable contains and the alert comes up 3 times after each other, iterating from 0 to 2 without the code being executed before each alert.

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var images = [ "url(images/image1.png)","url(images/image2.png)","url(images/image3.png)" ];        
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < images.length; i = i+1) {
        $('.mobile').delay(2000).animate({'opacity': '0.0'}, 1000);
        $('.mobile').css("background-image", images[ i ]);
        $('.mobile').delay(2000).animate({'opacity': '1.0'}, 1000);
        alert(i);
    };

});
```

So to recap, I want to show each background image in the array with a delay before the next image appears.

I am still quite new to jQuery so any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: You need to put a closure inside of your loop. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/750495/1485219).

Comment: @oleq not necessary in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var images = ["url(http://placehold.it/32/ffff00)", "url(http://placehold.it/32/ff0000)", "url(http://placehold.it/32/000000)"];

    function render(images) {
        var img = images.shift();
        images.push(img);

        $('.mobile').delay(2000).animate({
            'opacity': '0.0'
        }, 1000, function () {
            console.log(img)
            $(this).css("background-image", img).delay(2000).animate({
                'opacity': '1.0'
            }, 1000, function () {
                render(images);
            });
        });
    }

    render(images)

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ZvPyf/)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie the OP says `change a background of a div with class ".mobile"`, so there are no 3 divs

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie i think the OP was complaining about the following behavior http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ZvPyf/3/

Comment: +1: A recursive update is appropriate in this instance (but will require more explanation for the asker).

Comment: Thanks this worked like a charm!! Is there a way to go back to image 1 when the last image is reached?

Comment: @Steve-o-graph a more proper solution could be http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ZvPyf/5/

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies with your JQuery selector, `$('.mobile')` will select all elements that match the class selector, so all your elements are having their background image change with each loop.

You could use [`eq(i)`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) to select the correct element based on the index, like so:

```
for (i = 0; i < images.length; i = i+1) {
    var $item = $('.mobile').eq(i);
    $item.delay(2000).animate({'opacity': '0.0'}, 1000);
    $item.css("background-image", images[ i ]);
    $item.delay(2000).animate({'opacity': '1.0'}, 1000);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things. If the opacity is "0.0" then image will not be displayed. If you want something to be done after the animation is complete, pass a callback function.